# Extract Word tables in Excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a Word with a lot of tables and I want to extract the tables from Word to Excel, but each table in a different sheet.In between the tables, i have a lot of paragraphs, but i only want the tables. I have found something online, but it does not work.

```
from docx.api import Document
import os. path
import pandas as pd

path=('SF.docx')
document=Document(path)
output_path=('Output')
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('{}/docx_tables.xlsx'.format(output_path),engine='xlsxwriter')
for i in range(len(document.tables)):
    table=document.tables[i]
    data=[]
    keys=None
    row_data=None
    for j,row in(table.rows):
        text=(cell.text for cell in row.cells)
        if j == 0:
            keys=tuple(text)
            continue
        row_data = dict(zip(keys,text))
        data.append(row_data)
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='N{}'.format(i))
writer.save()
```

In the above code, ‘path’ is the docx file path and ‘output_path’ is the path of the folder where the excel file will be saved.

And the error is this:

> ```
> for j,row in(table.rows): TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable _Row object
> ```

And for every table in every sheet, i need it to be copied 2 times in the right of them, if it is possible.

If you have another way to extract all the tables from word to excel in different sheets, please write it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.rows` returns an iterator whih yelds a `_Row` object at each iteration. When you write

```
for j,row in(table.rows):
```

Python expects to have a 2-elements sequence, so it can assign the first element to `j` and the second to `row`; you probably wanted to do

```
for j,row in enumerate(table.rows):
```

Comment: this did not gave me any error, but It did not work. I did not extract any tables. so the issue is with the whole code. Can you help me with a different code for this please?

Comment: The code seems ok. I run it on a very simple docx with two tables in it, and it worked. Perhaps there is some issue with your input file. For instance the documentation for `python.docx` states that a table nested within revision marks will not appear in the `document.tables` list

Comment: Ok it worked. and can you help me please with something else? i need all the tables to be copied another 2 times in the same sheet with 2 or 3 blank columns between them and how to make all the column width bigger in every sheet. The output gave me 25 sheets.

Comment: Hey man, i have another issue if you can help me. the same code. For the first table, it makes a sheet, but it does not write anything, and for the rest of the tables works just fine. Why does it not work for the first table?

Comment: And for other word documents, i have an error 'list index out of range' at 'text=(cell.text for cell in row.cells)'